# What does the C++ compiler do in these cases for implicit type conversion?

Tags: c++

Working through a bug today we realized that we were bit by an implicit type conversion.

`int64_t result = intA * intB;`

In the case where intA and intB are both positive `int`, they can overflow at values > 2^31.

I would expect a similar issue with the following code:

`int64_t result = (intA * intB) - int64A`

But it seems in practice as if we aren't overflowing on the result of `intA * intB`.

Is that right? If so, why? I read through some of the implicit type conversion rules for C++ to try and understand if it might be because the int64A operand is 64-bits but couldn't find anything conclusive.

Comment: `(intA * intB)` is always performed in `int` precision.  If there is some code with output you don't understand please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the expected output and the actual output. Note that signed integer overflow may cause *undefined behaviour* in which case any output can happen.

Comment: Your compiler may be multiplying these values in 64-bit registers and so it seems to work, but that behaviour is not guaranteed.

Comment: If it overflows, it's UB. One possible UB (among an infinite number of possibilities) is "behave as if the operands were converted to `int64_t`".

Comment: It will more useful if you mention which compiler you used.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming 32-bit `int` here.

C++ makes this complicated with the addition of user-defined conversions, but let's assume that user-defined conversions aren't being considered here.

For most arithmetic operations on integers (e.g. not shifts), you get the following conversions (this is from memory...):

- Each operand is converted to `int` if it is narrower<sup>1</sup> than `int`, and all values of its type can be represented by `int`.
- Each operand is then converted to `unsigned` if it is narrower than `unsigned`.
- Each operand is then converted to the wider type of the two operand types, if one of the types is wider.
- If they are the same width, but one is unsigned, then the unsigned type is chosen.

The first two steps are called "integer promotion" and the second two steps are part of the "usual arithmetic conversions".

So, if you want to do 64-bit multiplication,

```
int x, y;
// Always done with int
int r = x * y; // 32-bit
// These are always done with int64_t
int64_t r = (int64_t)x * y;
int64_t r = x * (int64_t)y;
int64_t r = (int64_t)x * (int64_t)y;
// This is a 32-bit multiplication, you probably don't want this...
// The RESULT is converted to 64 bit
int64_t r = x * y; // 32-bit
// Same thing...
int64_t r = (int64_t)(x * y); // 32-bit
```

The subtraction happens to the multiplication result, so if the multiplication result is 64-bit, then the subtraction will be done with 64 bits.

**HOWEVER:** As soon as you overflow with *signed* integer arithmetic, the results are undefined!  This means that if `x * y` overflows, the compiler is allowed to do anything it wants.  Maybe it gives you the 64-bit result.  Maybe it crashes.  Maybe it formats your hard drive.  Maybe things behave oddly in your program.

In practice this is "bounded undefined behavior" so it probably will just cause you to scratch your head and curse rather than crash your program outright.

---

<sup>1</sup>: "Narrower" is not technically the term used in the standard.